# Insert ≥ character in Database

Tags: java, database, oracle10g, database-administration

I want to insert ≥ in one of the columns of the table. The data type of the column is VARCHAR2 and the NLS character set is WE8MSWIN1252. Please suggest. As I have tried changing the data type to NVARCHAR2, NCHAR, NCLOB. It doesn't work. I can insert by unistr but I don't want to do that. Is thers any way I can insert this character?

Comment: have you tried escaping it

Comment: is ≥ contained in WE8MSWIN1252 ?

Comment: no, it is  not. check  codepoint U+2265 at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_(computing)#Comparison_table

Comment: 1) you really are able to insert it by `unistr`? What is the result if you then select the value from the table? 2) How do you try to change the data type? What is the error message?

Comment: Create your database with the AL32UTF8 character set.

Comment: I think it can only be inserted when the character set is AL32UTF8. Also in Db, one can insert it using 'unistr 2265' but I want to insert coming through jdbc and would not be right to put this thing there.